# Search Files (Preferably with index) on Windows 2000 Server

Tags: windows, search, windows-server-2000

I have many files on a windows server 2000 machine that is setup to act as a networked disk drive, is there anyway I can index the files and make that index available as a search to more people than just me? Bonus if the index can look inside of documents such as readme.txt? If there is no easy way to do this globaly (for all users) Is there a  way I could generate and store an index locally on my computer?

If this is the wrong place to ask this question, any advice on community more suited?

Answer (score 1):

For this type of functionality (native to windows) you need to upgrade to server 2008 and the clients should be vista or higher.  Yuo can then use windows search services to search the fileserver.

Another option under 2008 is to install [search server express](http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/searchserverexpress/en/us/technical-resources.aspx)

Under windows 2000 your only option is to configure and enable [index services](http://www.simongibson.com/intranet/indexserv/default.asp)

Answer (score 1):

may be "google desktop enterprise" ? i hear that it can search on network shares ....